# Lista encadeada inserção no fim

Tags: c

Olá gostaria de saber o que inserir no condicional dentro da função, para adicionar os elementos no fim da lista enquanto fossem diferentes de 0...
já tentei várias maneiras e não consegui...

```
    typedef struct node{ // Struct para ser usada como nó...
        int data;
        struct node *next;  
    };

    void insert(node *lista, int a){ // Adicionar elementos no fim da lista
        node *ptr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        ptr->data = a;

        if(){

        }else{

    }

    int main(){
        //Variáveis
        int n = 1, // Número que vai ser adicionado
        node *lista; // Lista
        while(n!=0){
            printf("Que numero adicionar?\n");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            insert(lista, n);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só poderá alocar memória e criar uma estrutura do tipo *node* depois que o usuário digitar algum número diferente de zero, caso contrário o programa irá encerrar. Em seguida, apenas verifique se é a primeira vez que está criando um *node* para iniciar a *lista*, se não for o caso, então anexe o novo *node* no final da lista. Isso vai ocorrer até o usuário digitar zero e sair do *while*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

typedef struct node { // Struct para ser usada como nó...
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void insert(node *&lista, int numero) { // Adicionar elementos no fim da lista

    node *ptr = NULL;
    node *lista_temp = lista;

    if (numero != 0) {

        ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        ptr->data = numero;
        ptr->next = NULL;

        if (lista == NULL) {

            lista = ptr;
        }
        else {

            while (lista_temp->next != NULL) {

                lista_temp = lista_temp->next;
            }

            lista_temp->next = ptr;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    //Variáveis
    int numero = 1; // Número que vai ser adicionado
    node *lista = NULL; // Lista
    node *ptr = NULL; // Ponteiro temporário

    while (numero != 0) {
        printf("Que numero adicionar?\nNumero:");
        scanf_s("%d", &numero);
        insert(lista, numero);
    }

    //Usando uma variável temporária para não perder a referência da lista
    ptr = lista;

    while (ptr->next != NULL) {

        printf("%i -> ", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    printf("NULL\n");

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Lucas, usando seu código, eu adicionei 4 números mas ele só me mostrou os 3 primeiro que eu adicinei... o que acha que pode ser?

Comment: Pela cláusula while dele, isso é esperado. Para resolver, troca o while por um do-while. E dá uns upvote se as respostas ajudarem...

Comment: Tem razão Ken, não tinha percebido, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tenha em mente que você deve armazenar a referência para o primeiro nó da lista.
A cada inserção, você deve procurar pelo ultimo nó e em seguida fazer com que o próximo dele seja o novo nó.
Além disso, sua lista começava não inicializada e não era inicializada pela função de inserção.

```
typedef struct node{ // Struct para ser usada como nó...
        int data;
        struct node *next;
}node;
    node *insert(node *lista, int a){ // Adicionar elementos no fim da lista
    if(lista == NULL){
            node *aux = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            aux->data = a;
            aux-> next = NULL;
            return aux;
    }
    node *ptr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->data = a;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    if(a != 0){
            node *aux = lista;
            while(aux->next != NULL){
                    aux = aux->next;
            }
            aux->next = ptr;
            return lista;
    }
    return lista;
}

int main(){
        //Variáveis
        int n = 1; // Número que vai ser adicionado
        node *lista = NULL; // Lista
        while(n!=0){
                printf("Que numero adicionar?\n");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                lista = insert(lista, n);
}
```

Comment: Cara, não sei se você está usando alguma biblioteca, mas eu uso o dev c++, está falando aqui que na linha 7 o NULL não está declarado no escopo

Comment: Não usei nenhuma biblioteca além da stdio e da stdlib. Acho que se você substituir NULL por 0 é equivalente. Mas NULL deveria funcionar.

Comment: Funcionou mesmo cara, obrigado =)